# Laravel Snappy table not splitting over multiple pages

Tags: laravel, html-table, snappy

Laravel Snappy works great, but trying to fix this

[image]

The headers are good, but the table itself is not splitting and starting underneath the headers of the second page. Is this fixable? I am using the adminLTE theme.

Seen this page, but this does not solve it for me: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2367

Current code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered tree">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Cables</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Load in</th>
            <th>Load out</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>some data</td>
         <td>some data</td>
         <td>some data</td>
         <td>some data</td>
         <td>some data</td>
         <td>some data</td>
         <td>some data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.tree {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

add this code in style. Hope that will be work

Answer (score 0):

```
        .page-break {
            page-break-after: always;
        }

        .page-break:last-child {
            page-break-after: avoid;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over `page-break-inside`, as suggested by the previous answer?